# Scrypt npm install fails with error C compiler cannot create executable

Tags: error, installation

Can you please help me with this error?

```
dhcp-rhodes-571:harberger-token kishorpatil$ sudo npm install scrypt

> scrypt@6.0.3 preinstall /Users/kishorpatil/blockchain/radical-markets/harberger-token/node_modules/scrypt
> node node-scrypt-preinstall.js

Error: Error: Command failed: ./configure
configure: error: in `/Users/kishorpatil/blockchain/radical-markets/harberger-token/node_modules/scrypt/scrypt/scrypt-1.2.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details


> scrypt@6.0.3 install /Users/kishorpatil/blockchain/radical-markets/harberger-token/node_modules/scrypt
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/kishorpatil/blockchain/radical-markets/harberger-token/node_modules/scrypt/build'
gyp ERR! System Darwin 17.6.0
gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/kishorpatil/blockchain/radical-markets/harberger-token/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/kishorpatil/blockchain/radical-markets/harberger-token/package.json'
npm WARN harberger-token No description
npm WARN harberger-token No repository field.
npm WARN harberger-token No README data
npm WARN harberger-token No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kishorpatil/.npm/_logs/2018-07-15T14_50_36_660Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Are you on windows, linux or macos?

Comment: Mac OS High Sierra

Comment: Do you have the C compiler installed? Probably you are better asking in stackoverflow.com seems like a configuration problem.

Comment: I confirmed I have GCC installed on my machine by running                                  dhcp-rhodes-571:harberger-token kishorpatil$ gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Phew .. finally figured out this is NPM permissions issue on Mac. I changed ownership of following directories from root to my user name :

- sudo chown -R  /usr/local/share/
- sudo chown -R  /usr/local/bin/
- sudo chown -R  /usr/local/lib/node_modules/

Comment: It is a bad idea to change ownership for files in global directories to your user. I'd suggest to try using a node manager like [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) that will install node inside your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue till yesterday,
please refer to this link
https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#compiling-native-addon-modules
I followed instructions to manually setup the environment.
install vs 2017 community version with "c++ for desktop development" workload as mentioned and do the next steps. this much should be enough to get you running.
Thanks, good luck

Comment: I'm on MAC High Sierra .. sorry I didn't add to original questions. I believe your answer / instructions are for windows

Comment: yes, it is for windows, I don't know the right tools for mac OS